# How to implement a crosstable in JPA

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have 3 database tables:

**user**

- id: int PK
- Name: string

**settings**

- id: int PK
- Name: string

**user_settings**

- user_id PK
- Settings_id PK
- info

and the corresponding Entity classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class user {
  @Id
  private int id;
  …

@Entity
@Table(name = "settings")
public class settings {
  @Id
  private int id;
  …
```

what is the correct procedure to create the entity class for the crosstable user_settings.

I´ve created a primary key class.

```
public class UserSettingsPk implements Serializable {
private Long userId;
private Long settingsId;
```

And a user settings Entity class like this, because I want to have an easy Access to the ids and the settings class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_settings")
@IdClass(UserSettingsPk.class)
public class UserSettings {

@Id
@Column(name = "user_id")
private long userId;

@Id
@Column(name = "settings_id")
private long settingsId;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "settings_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Settings settings;
```

But with this implementation I have the problem, that the Settings variable is null, wenn ich insert a new entry to the settings table where I only set the ids.

The solution that works, is to create a primary key class like that:

```
public class UserSettingsPk implements Serializable {

@Column(name = "user_id")
private long userId;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "settings_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Settings settings;
```

and to embed the id in the usersettings class:

```
public class UserSettings implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private UserSettingsPk userSettingsPk;
```

Then everything works but is very complicated to retrieve.

Get the Settings info

```
userSettings.getUserSettingsPk().getSettings().getInfo();
```

And the jpa query are also complex. I have to use

```
@Query("SELECT us FROM UserSettings us WHERE us.userSettingsPk.userId = :userId and us.userSettingsPk.settings.id = :settingsId")
```

instead of

```
findUserSettingsByUserIdAndSettingsId(userId , settingsId)
```

What is the best practice to implement a crosstable like this?

Comment: Why do you need to query the `user_settings`, is there any particular reason? I'm asking this since, usually when setting up many to many relations with JPA/Hibernate you don't need to concern yourself with querying the cross-table

Comment: Hi, when the user adds user specificic settings, then he calls AddSettings(serttingsId). Then the Server adds the setting and returns the one specific setting as combination of the settings and the user_settings table.So i dont need all settings for a user here and I also dont need all users for a setting, so i select the crosstable.